# C# How to Click Button automatically via WebBrowser

Tags: c#, button, browser, submit

The Html code of my click page is :

```
<input type="submit" id="publishButton-ns" class="ubtn ubtn-block"
 name="publish" tabindex="10" value="Publish Post">
```

I tried this code for clicking:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("publishButton-ns").InvokeMember("click");
```

but this not found the button.

Comment: Look at @Ponmalar 's answer at the bottom

Answer (score 29):

This may help you.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");  
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)  
{  
   if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))  
   {  
        el.InvokeMember("Click");  
   }  
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you waiting for the page to load first? You should bind a function in your code to wait for the page to load, them click the button:

```
static void form1_Load() {
    // ...
    webBrowser1.onDocumentReady += webBrowser_DocumentReady;
}

static void webBrowser1_DocumentReady() {
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("publishButton-ns").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a combination of @adam's suggestion and capitalize `Click`

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document
        .GetElementById("ctl00_main_LoginExpoPlanIt_LoginButton")
        .InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Just tested this and it didn't work with "click" but did with "Click" :)

I'm using .net 4

Comment: Its still not found the button. The error is "nullreferenceException"

Comment: mdmullinax, thanks for your input.  It also didn't work for me with a LOWER CASE "c" in "click" but the UPPER CASE "C" did work.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This only applies when `runat="server"` is set, not applicable in this case but leaving for others just in case, my apologies on missing that in the question.

ASP.Net changes the name of elements it renders based on the structure they are in, you can try the following to get the final name of the element:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<%=publishButton-ns.ClientID%>").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: There is no runat="server" on the input element, so the ASP.NET engine won't touch it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery and then do something like this $("#publishButton-ns").click();

http://www.jQuery.com/