# How To Click A Button That Has No ID or Tag using the webbrowser control's

Tags: c#, automation

Im trying to click a button on a website automatically that doesnt have any ID or Tags..

```
<a class="mrs mlm _42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h" role="button" href="/ajax/plans/create/dialog.php?source=2&amp;source_dashboard_filter=upcoming" rel="dialog" tabindex="0"><i class="mrs img sp_bf4jqs sx_7c6e2e"></i>Create Event</a>
```

I can't figure out how to do this any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should help:

[C# How to Click Button auttomaticly via WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233151/c-sharp-how-to-click-button-auttomaticly-via-webbrowser)

Basically, with no ID to select on, you'll have to get all the anchor tags and loop through them until you find the one you need. If the set of classes it has is unique, that could be a good field to check to see if it's the one you need.

You should be able to use the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlelement.cssclass(v=vs.95).aspx) property to find the class string.