# How do i click on a website button?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm navigating in the constructor first for testing

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumpage/393");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
```

Then in the DocumentCompleted event:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {

                HtmlElementCollection items = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"); 
                foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
                {
                    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                    {
                        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("onclick").InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
            }
```

When i make inspect element on the addMessage button i see:

```
<span class="addMessage" onclick="location='http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393/טבע_ומזג_אוויר/מזג_האוויר'">  | הוספת הודעה</span>
```

But i'm getting null on the line:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("onclick").InvokeMember("click");
```

What i want to do is to click on the addMessage button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233151/c-sharp-how-to-click-button-auttomaticly-via-webbrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("onclick").InvokeMember("click");
```

to

```
item.InvokeMember("Click");
```

item is already the element you want to have so you just need to invoke the member click on it.

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.WebBrowserWindow.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("Click");
                    break;
                }

            }
```